# how to store a data from a database table into an array in zend

Tags: zend-framework

Hi i am currently getting some data from my database table and printing it in my zend view. i want that data to be stored in an array instead of showing it in the view. can anyone please tell me how to do that in zend.

Comment: show your code: getting some data from database and printing it in zend view. Unfortunately, I'm not a psychic.

Comment: Show code, or at least tell what kind of classes do you use for DB. Zend is a set of around 1500 classes.

Comment: @Szymon good chances its Zend_Db he is curious about

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well if you are outputting it to the view then its already in a array?
if you have something like

```
$myTable->fetchAll();
```

Then just:

```
$myDataArray =     $myTable->fetchAll();
```

And everything is in $myDataArray. Or do you mean not as objects but a true array? Then add:

```
$myDataArray =     $myTable->fetchAll()->toArray();
```

I suggest you post some code so we can help you better.

Comment: well i actually wanted to store that $myTable->fetchAll() data into a file. so i thought to store it in array first and then into the file. but i got a way to enter it into the file directly. thanks

Comment: hi do you have any idea how to store the same array into a .CSV file.

Comment: @Naphstor so just to be sure you asked the wrong question? You know peoples take time to answer on here. Better if you ask the right question first instead of making everyone lose there time.